# Missing ansible.builtin.ssh?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to figure out why ssh is missing from ansible builtin.

[Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html) states that `This connection plugin is part of ansible-core and included in all Ansible installations.`

So I try following:

```bash
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash python:3.11-bullseye -c "apt-get update && apt-get -y install ansible && ansible --version && ansible-doc ansible.builtin.ssh"
```

I get following output:

```
ansible 2.10.8
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
[WARNING]: module ansible.builtin.ssh not found in: /root/.ansible/plugins/modules:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules
```

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, should `ansible.builtin.ssh` not be available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know that *ansible.builtin.ssh* is a `connection`  `plugin`. When you take a look at the *ansible-doc* common option [--type](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-doc.html#cmdoption-ansible-doc-t):

> -t , --type : Choose which plugin type (defaults to “module”). Available plugin types are : (‘become’, ‘cache’, ‘callback’, ‘cliconf’, ‘connection’, ‘httpapi’, ‘inventory’, ‘lookup’, ‘netconf’, ‘shell’, ‘vars’, ‘module’, ‘strategy’, ‘test’, ‘filter’, ‘role’, ‘keyword’)

you'll see that *ansible-doc* is by default looking for a `module`. As a result your command

```bash
shell> ansible-doc ansible.builtin.ssh
```

is looking for a module *ansible.builtin.ssh* which is missing

> [WARNING]: module ansible.builtin.ssh not found ...

The solution is simple. Try to find the `connection` plugin

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t connection ansible.builtin.ssh
```

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBotka! So ansible-doc confirms that ansible.builtin.ssh is not missing, I wonder if it's possible to use that in my playbook to specify address to ssh into? I'm trying to perform some remote tasks using linode rescue mode through lish, and later switch to plain ssh. But when calling-in through lish I am accessing the host through different ssh address and I thought I can use `ansible.builtin.ssh` to specify different ssh address to reach my host.

Comment: A different host can be set by [delegate_to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#controlling-where-tasks-run-delegation-and-local-actions).